# Are there any known backward compatibility issues with upgrading Newtonsoft.JSON?

Tags: json.net, compatibility

Are there any known backward compatibility issues with upgrading Newtonsoft.JSON, specifically in my case from 4.5.9 to 6.0.8?

Comment: I work on an client application that used web api 1 which depended on newtonsoft.json 4.x that we upgraded to web api 2 that depends on v6.0.5 of newtonsoft json without seeing any issues.  The objects that were getting serialized/ deserialized were fairly simple.

Comment: If you start at [james.newtonking.com](http://james.newtonking.com/) and go back through the pages you will be able to find all the changes. (I suggest you go back to version 4.5.8 and work forwards from that.)

Comment: I've successfully upgraded multiple projects from 6.x to 10.x without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any incompatibility issues with mine. I have upgraded mine from v5.0.8 to v6.0.8 and it works fine. But I thought just to check out the changes from v4.5.9 for you as I am also curious.

So, here is the list of changes made from v4.5.9 to v6.0.8.

```
v4.5.10
Change - Improved duplicate object reference id error message

v4.5.11
Change - Silverlight and Windows Phone assemblies in NuGet are strong named again
Change - Improved CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver camel casing property names
Change – Explicit JValue conversions are more flexible when converting values

v5.0.1
Change - NaN and Infinity floating point values are serialized as strings by default
Change - Minor breaking changes to JsonSchema type
Change - Upgraded Windows Phone assembly to WP8
Change - DateTime IDictionary keys are now serialized in ISO date format
Change - DataContractAttribute is no longer inherited to match DataConctractSerializer behavior
Change - StringEnumConverter converts empty strings to null for nullable enums
Change - Guids serialize to a binary UUID in BSON instead of a string
Remove - Removed SL4 library
Remove - Removed WP7 library

v5.0.2
Remove - Removed WP8 library

v5.0.3
(Fix)

v5.0.4
Change - Changed .NET 4.5 portable library and WinRT library to use compiled expressions reflection

v5.0.5
Change - Changed some explicit interface methods on JArray to public to support use with ImpromtuInterface

v5.0.6
(New features and fixes)

v5.0.7
Change - Extension data is now written when serializing

v5.0.8
(Fix)

v6.0.1
Change - Changed assembly version to 6.0.0.0
Change - .NET 4 Portable build targets MonoTouch and MonoDroid in NuGet package
Change - .NET 4 Portable build targets WP8 and SL5 instead of WP7 and SL4
Removed - DefaultMemberSearchFlags on DefaultContractResolver is obsolete
Removed - SerializeObjectAsync, DeserializeObjectAsync, PopulateObjectAsync on JsonConvert are obsolete

v6.0.2
(New feature)

v6.0.3
Change - Blank XML elements will be written as an empty string instead of null
Change - JValue with a null value will be written as null instead of empty string
Change - DateFormatString is now used when reading JSON

v6.0.4
Change - Limited integer parsing size to JavaScript integer size
Change - Validation that numbers don't end with an invalid character

v6.0.5
(New features and fixes)

v6.0.6
Change - Omit fields array for F# discriminated union serialization when there are no fields
Change - Escape property names in path on readers/writers/tokens when a name contains special characters
Change - Provide line numbers for end tokens on JTokenReader

v6.0.7
(New features and fixes)

v6.0.8
(New feature and fixes)
```

I hope this post could help others who is making decision to upgrade or not.

Cheers,
Sam